# Is it possible to have a select box with an input field option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I want to have a select box that besides the given options allows to set a value manually. I am not a hundred percent sure if that is possible but I think I have seen it before. On the [w3school page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) for `select` I couldn't find anything relevant.

As I am working Rails, I also checked the [APIDock page](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) for the `select_tag` form helper, but there I also couldn't find anything.

Comment: I guess you are looking for something like this http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Kind of, but as this would allow me to search in the existing options (associated AR objects) I want to be able to enter the value for a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's a very common functionality, what you are looking for is not part of the standard HTML (5 or not) controls.

To achieve the desired effect you have to use a JavaScript framework.

The good news is that there are a lot of frameworks and/or plugins doing this. The bad news is that you will have to spend some time playing with a couple until you find one you're happy with.

The two most used JS frameworks, [jQuery](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery%20combobox%20allow%20free%20text) and [Bootstrap](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=bootstrap%20combobox%20allow%20free%20text), have dozens of plugins that does this, just search for them.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Another option would then be to implement it myself with JS, even though I have no idea how to do so..

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. It's one of those cases where it's counterproductive to reinvent the wheel. You'll end up using a JavaScript framework anyway.